# Google Cloud Messaging Response 401, pushjack

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-messaging

For my python server I am using the "pushjack" library for sending GCM push notifications to my android device.

On my javascript client, I use the project number on the Overview page of the Google Developers Consolde as my senderID. When I tap the screen the senderID is sent and I receive a registrationID back which is then sent to the python server using XHR post. I then use the API key provided on the Credentials page for sending the message.

Here's the python server code:

```
from pushjack import GCMClient, create_gcm_config

    config = create_gcm_config({
        'GCM_API_KEY': 'my_api_key'
    })

    client = GCMClient(config)

    registration_id = message ## Gotten from javascript client using XHR post

    data = {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}

    res = client.send(registration_id, data)

    print(res.responses)
    print(res.registration_ids)
    print(res.successes)
    print(res.failures)
    print(res.errors)
    print(res.canonical_ids)
```

I keep getting "[Response [401]]" and receive no notifications on my android device.

I've whitelisted my server's IP address, but I've also tried to send the message with the server's IP removed from the whitelist but I still receive the 401 response.

The "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" is also enabled in the API's section.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your problem is in the authentication process: `HTTP 401` is "Unauthorized", similar to `HTTP 403` "Forbidden". Check your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP StatusCode 401 means, that your API Key is not valid. This is a curl example to check if your API Key is valid.

```
# api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

# curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

See http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html